# How to check for a collision between two html elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, 2d-games

I've been working on a text based game, and I've run across the problem of creating a function that checks for a collision between two elements; a ball that you move with arrow keys, and a pipe (think flappy bird sorta). After quite a bit of research, and some of my own experimentation I still am unable to make it work.

Here is my current function:

```
function collision(div1, div2) {
    var ballX = div1.offset().left;
    var ballY = div1.offset().top;
    var ballHeight = div1.outerHeight(true);
    var ballWidth = div1.outerWidth(true);
    var fullBallHeight = ballY + ballHeight;
    var fullBallWidth = ballX + ballWidth;
    var pipeX = div2.offset().left;
    var pipeY = div2.offset().top;
    var pipeHeight = div2.outerHeight(true);
    var pipeWidth = div2.outerWidth(true);
    var fullPipeHeight = pipeY + pipeHeight;
    var fullPipeWidth = pipeX + pipeWidth;

    if (fullBallHeight < pipeY || ballY > fullPipeHeight || fullBallWidth < pipeX || ballX > fullPipeWidth) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And calling the function:

```
  if (collision($("#ball"), $(".pipe")) == true) {
    //code for game over
  } else if (collision($("#ball"), $(".pipe")) == false) {
    //calling loop function for ball animation
    loop();
  }
```

All input is appreciated, I will try almost anything at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify that your variables are capturing the correct positions? Then I can help you with your _if_.

Comment: I just checked the variables fullBallHeight, and pipeY. fullBallHeight is returning a value of NaN, and pipeY is undefined. So am I using outerHeight, and .offset.top incorrectly?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, try [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Comment: Also, you're passing elem1 and elem2 to your function but then you're using div1 and div2 inside it.

Comment: Yes! My variables are returning numeric values. However my end game code went off half cocked. So my functions if statement has some logic errors.

Comment: the elem1 and div1 was a question typo, thanks for pointing that out, my code is correct.

Comment: So, now let's go to the actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 2D collision to occur, you need 4 things to happen *at the same time* (so it is an *and*, not *or*):

- Ball's bottom must be below pipe's top (fullBallHeight > pipeY)
- Ball's top must be above pipe's bottom (ballY < fullPipeHeight)
- Ball's right must be to the right of pipe's left (fullBallWidth > pipeX)
- Ball's left must be to the left of pipe's right (ballX < fullPipeWidth)

[image: Image from http://jonathanwhiting.com/tutorial/collision/]

(Image from http://jonathanwhiting.com/tutorial/collision/, which I recommend you to read)

So here's the resulting condition:

```
if (fullBallHeight > pipeY && ballY < fullPipeHeight && fullBallWidth > pipeX && ballX < fullPipeWidth) {
```

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect. Thanks for walking me through my syntax errors as well!